# Unable to catch error in React from Express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, try-catch, react-context

I have an issue with the handling of errors coming from my Express signup API in the Client Side. I am using React with context to create a global state in my website.

I built the contexte provider in React like so :

```js
const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState()

    function signup(email, password) {
        if (emailRe.test(email) && passwordRe.test(password)) {
            axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users/create', {
                email: email,
                password: password
            }).then((res) => {
                setCurrentUser(res);
                return res;
            }).catch((error) => {
                return new Error("Can't register")
            });
        };
    }
    const value = {
        currentUser,
        signup
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

And on my registration Page, I have the following code :

```js
function Registration(){

    //some code

    const { signup } = useAuth()
    const onSubmit = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()

        if (password1===password2){
            try {
                let res = await signup(email,password1);
            } catch {
                setEmailError(true) //<- this is where it does not work, I can't catch the error
            }
        }
    }
    return(
       ////
    )
}
```

This issue is that I can't handle the issue coming from the signup function in the registration page. Is there a way to keep the current structure or do I have to move the whole signup function inside registration (but I won't be able to change very easily the contexte value then).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

`return new Error("Can't register")`

to

`throw new Error("Can't register")`

and then catch the error like this

```
try {
  let res = await signup(email, password1);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
  setEmailError(true);
}
```

Comment: Now when an error occurs, I get "Unhandled Rejection (Error):"Can't register""

Comment: Isn't it what you need?

Comment: I still get the same error.... Let me check again if I can find anything

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can you see the console log? If yes, this is what you need, isn't it?

Comment: It does log the error but doesn't set the email error. Anyway I think that the idea behind all of this code is wrong, I put the axios in the registration page and it work correctly now. Thanks for the help!